# Why use Thread.sleep in flink decrease performance obviously?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, thread-sleep

We are comparing storm and flink. What we do is develop storm topology logic to flink app.
There is using Thread.sleep(100) in the storm topology bolt, but when using in flink app, flink app performance is not good.
Here is our test result with Flink parallelism 80:

Consume 161073 data from kafka and compute our business logic in next task, and last sink result to file.
When using Thread.sleep(100) in Compute and Redis task, it spend about 4 minutes. But if we not using Thread.sleep(100), it only spend 6 seconds.

[My Flink app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Tw4G.png)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is mainly due to back pressure

Back pressure will cause upstream processing to be interrupted, waiting for downstream operators to consume

For more information, please refer to

https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.14/docs/ops/monitoring/back_pressure/

Answer (score 0):

I'm wondering where `Thread.sleep(100)` is located at? If it happens in the function that processes data, that makes sense. `Thread.sleep(100)` will be called every time a record is processed. Since there are 161073 records in total, the overall time of sleeping is 161073 / 80 * 100 / 1000 = 201.3 seconds, which is about 4 minutes.